# Do Not Display Tabs if There is Only One Fragment Enabled

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-pageradapter

I have an activity that has two fragments, in two tabs: description tab and comments tab. Comments tab is optional, so when the admin adds a description he can enable or disable comments. If he disables it I would like to display description, but make it look like it not tabbed, ie. hide the tab from activity and still show the content.

So, if both fragments are enabled it should look like this:

[image]

Right now if I disable second tab I get this:

[image]

But THIS is what I would like to have:

[image]

Pager adapter:

```
class RestauranPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private int mNumOfTabs;

    RestauranPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new RestauranFragmentDescription();
            case 1:
                return new RestauranFragmentComments();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.RestauranTabs);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.description));
// tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.comments));
if (!Restauran.getComments_enabled()) {
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.comments));
}
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.RestauranViewpager);
final RestauranPagerAdapter adapter = new RestauranPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

FloatingActionButton fabGoToMap = findViewById(R.id.fabGoToMap);
fabGoToMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
});
```

Comment: what about get the current tab and set the title to blank " " and set the tabIndicatorColor to primary color it will become what you are looking for

Comment: @vikaskumar I like that solution, but I would like it more if it would be possible to remove the tab, but leave the fragment...

Comment: @vikaskumar Also, would this mean it would be blank space above the description text, where the tab title was?

Comment: yeah, but for the tab, you can try set visibility of the tab to GONE and you will be left only with viewpager. then it will be what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @vikaskumar If I do not find a solution I would like more over the weekend I will let you know so you can re post your answer and I would accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: yeah sure thanks :)

Comment: @vikaskumar Hey Vikas, I tried this solution and I liked it a lot :) if you would like to add your answer I will accept it. Thanks again :)

Comment: great posting in a minute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide the tab layout when you have the only description enabled like below

```
tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

so your code should look like this

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.RestauranTabs);
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

//adding the default one
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.description));

if (!Restauran.getComments_enabled()) {
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.comments));
}else{
    tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

//rest goes as it is
final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.RestauranViewpager);
final RestauranPagerAdapter adapter = new RestauranPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

FloatingActionButton fabGoToMap = findViewById(R.id.fabGoToMap);
fabGoToMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Best and cleanest solution I found :)